# jQuery Multiple Array JSON Alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've been trying this all night but can't seem to get

```
{"files": [
  {
    "name": "picture1.jpg",
    "size": 902604,
    "url": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture1.jpg",
    "thumbnailUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/thumbnail\/picture1.jpg",
    "deleteUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture1.jpg",
    "deleteType": "DELETE"
  },
  {
    "name": "picture2.jpg",
    "size": 841946,
    "url": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture2.jpg",
    "thumbnailUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/thumbnail\/picture2.jpg",
    "deleteUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture2.jpg",
    "deleteType": "DELETE"
  }
]}
```

I've been trying to get the name of each file...So what i've done is to this.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data.result);
        for(var i in obj.files){
        var urlstring;
        urlstring = obj.files[i].name;
        alert(urlstring);
        }
```

But somehow it doesn't allow me to alert out the name of each one...Any idea how i can go about doing it?

Comment: This code works fine for me. Are you sure the content in `data.result` is the same as in the code above?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't allow you to alert out the name of each one", what does it do instead? Are you getting and runtime errors?

Comment: The code displayed above just doesn't do anything. No errors thrown, but it doesn't display anything either. (At least nothing visible...Very new to jQuery, no idea how to debug it...)

Comment: @user2587774 If using chrome just press `ctrl+shift+j` for console window.I would suggest your to use `firebug` tool to dubug JS

Answer (score 1):

Assuming,

```
var data  = {"files": [
  {
    "name": "picture1.jpg",
    "size": 902604,
    "url": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture1.jpg",
    "thumbnailUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/thumbnail\/picture1.jpg",
    "deleteUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture1.jpg",
    "deleteType": "DELETE"
  },
  {
    "name": "picture2.jpg",
    "size": 841946,
    "url": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture2.jpg",
    "thumbnailUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/thumbnail\/picture2.jpg",
    "deleteUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture2.jpg",
    "deleteType": "DELETE"
  }
]};
```

Try,

```
$.each(data, function(i, items) {
    $.each(items, function(j, item) {
       alert(item.name);
    });
});
```

**[Working fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/n4HN5/1/)**

---

## EDIT

Your data is badly formatted so you need to format it correctly.

Please have a look at following data, and working fiddle.

```
var data  = '{"files": ['+
'{"name": "picture1.jpg","size": 902604,"url":"http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture1.jpg","thumbnailUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/thumbnail\/picture1.jpg","deleteUrl": "http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture1.jpg","deleteType": "DELETE"},' +
'{"name":"picture2.jpg","size":841946,"url":"http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture2.jpg","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/example.org\/files\/thumbnail\/picture2.jpg","deleteUrl":"http:\/\/example.org\/files\/picture2.jpg","deleteType":"DELETE"}]}';

var obj = JSON.parse(data);

for(var i in obj.files){
        var urlstring;
        urlstring = obj.files[i].name;
        alert(urlstring);
}
```

### [Working fiddle with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/t4MjY/)

Comment: Excellent works very well :) Thanks so much! Do you mind explaning a bit of the code? Why does yours seem to work and my foreach method as that's what i normally do in PHP!

Comment: @user2587774 this is because you are getting JSON parsing err at `JSON.parse(data.result);` due to un-formatted JSON data.

Comment: @user2587774 i updated my ans with your code.Please check how data is formatted.mark it correct and close if find it right